# How to get files from server to my local machine using Git?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I need to clone the files from server to local machine using Git. After making changes to the fields I need to push them back to the server. I have public and private keys and the passphrase.

I am not sure how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: @maalls Windows 8.. I downloaded Putty but and loaded the private key .ppk file.. but I am not sure how to proceed after that.

Comment: putty is to access a remote server... I think your question is answer in the second chapters of the git documentation http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 please came back if you have still some questions after reading it.

Comment: @maalls I am sorry I forgot to mentions. I need to access the remote server

Comment: in this case check how to configure putty to access the server. If you have server hostname, the username, the private key and the passphrase you have all the elements.

But this will requires you to know how to use the command line in order to access the file and use the git command.

Comment: Yes I have all the credentials. Can you tell how to process further? Thanks!

Comment: putty doc ? then study command lines.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this depends on your operating system.
If you're on a Microsoft Windows machine head to http://git-scm.com/ and download an installer.
For most GNU/Linux distributions you can find git in your favourite package manager such as apt-get or rpm.

Once you have git installed on your local machine, you have to configure git for use with github.

```
§ git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
§ git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

You can optionally use a keypair or authenticate over https with your github username.

A very basic git workflow for beginners would look like this:

1) Clone your github repo to your local drive:

```
git clone https://github.com/*yourusername*/*yourreponame*/
```

2) Make your changes.

3) Commit your changes to the local version of your git repo:

```
git commit -a -m *your commit message*
```

4) Push your changes to the remote repository:

```
git push
```

For more detailed instructions on a basic git workflow please refer to the git website. For a more advanced workflow refer to the [successful branching model for git](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)